# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on youtube api

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

am getting a playlist video from youtube's api like this:

this is the video class:

https://app.quicktype.io?share=aNLIT2lKl4ecggFJMRhY

and the parsing is like this:

```
 let youtubeData = try JSONDecoder().decode(Video.self, from: data!)
            for item in youtubeData.items{
                print(item)
                self.titles.append(item.snippet.title)
                self.ids.append(item.contentDetails.videoID)
                self.images.append((item.snippet.thumbnails.standard?.url)!)
            }
```

and the link is:

```
            let link: String = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key=AIzaSyCZD5QOrfmfKKeu2FbiTXzhEEr96Ky6tew&playlistId=PLbJRbIvdAVXRdkBSpA25hugmJy_rOKOYu&part=snippet,contentDetails&maxResults=20"
```

this what am getting in postman:

```
    {
"kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
"etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/rADsLSpprHJE-fPnym42pRX8eww\"",
"pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 4,
    "resultsPerPage": 50
},
"items": [
    {
        "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
        "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/6yrUGyNtxoJ1dmT3Y8sRBJLBeXE\"",
        "id": "UExiSlJiSXZkQVZYUmRrQlNwQTI1aHVnbUp5X3JPS09ZdS41NkI0NEY2RDEwNTU3Q0M2",
        "snippet": {
            "publishedAt": "2018-08-17T02:56:10.000Z",
            "channelId": "UCqXAWrjSgLb0EPa_icPt-pw",
            "title": "Interview",
            "description": "",
            "thumbnails": {
                "default": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CjNr5Gpa4TE/default.jpg",
                    "width": 120,
                    "height": 90
                },
                "medium": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CjNr5Gpa4TE/mqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 320,
                    "height": 180
                },
                "high": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CjNr5Gpa4TE/hqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 480,
                    "height": 360
                },
                "standard": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CjNr5Gpa4TE/sddefault.jpg",
                    "width": 640,
                    "height": 480
                },
                "maxres": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/CjNr5Gpa4TE/maxresdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 1280,
                    "height": 720
                }
            },
            "channelTitle": "الدوري السعودي للمحترفين Saudi Pro League",
            "playlistId": "PLbJRbIvdAVXRdkBSpA25hugmJy_rOKOYu",
            "position": 0,
            "resourceId": {
                "kind": "youtube#video",
                "videoId": "CjNr5Gpa4TE"
            }
        },
        "contentDetails": {
            "videoId": "CjNr5Gpa4TE",
            "videoPublishedAt": "2018-07-28T19:04:42.000Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
        "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/9bldgOrkQOmEy3P6x_T4pJiqAss\"",
        "id": "UExiSlJiSXZkQVZYUmRrQlNwQTI1aHVnbUp5X3JPS09ZdS4yODlGNEE0NkRGMEEzMEQy",
        "snippet": {
            "publishedAt": "2018-08-17T02:59:16.000Z",
            "channelId": "UCqXAWrjSgLb0EPa_icPt-pw",
            "title": "ورشة عمل مراقبي ومنسقي المباريات - اليوم الختامي",
            "description": "",
            "thumbnails": {
                "default": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/t-sLCUA68R0/default.jpg",
                    "width": 120,
                    "height": 90
                },
                "medium": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/t-sLCUA68R0/mqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 320,
                    "height": 180
                },
                "high": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/t-sLCUA68R0/hqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 480,
                    "height": 360
                }
            },
            "channelTitle": "الدوري السعودي للمحترفين Saudi Pro League",
            "playlistId": "PLbJRbIvdAVXRdkBSpA25hugmJy_rOKOYu",
            "position": 1,
            "resourceId": {
                "kind": "youtube#video",
                "videoId": "t-sLCUA68R0"
            }
        },
        "contentDetails": {
            "videoId": "t-sLCUA68R0",
            "videoPublishedAt": "2018-07-28T17:01:42.000Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
        "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/Eue448TE2XiiTrzi8vuJICCFqwU\"",
        "id": "UExiSlJiSXZkQVZYUmRrQlNwQTI1aHVnbUp5X3JPS09ZdS4wMTcyMDhGQUE4NTIzM0Y5",
        "snippet": {
            "publishedAt": "2018-08-17T02:59:24.000Z",
            "channelId": "UCqXAWrjSgLb0EPa_icPt-pw",
            "title": "ورشة عمل مراقبي ومنسقي المباريات - اليوم الأول",
            "description": "ملخص اليوم الأول من ورشة عمل مراقبي ومنسقي المباريات والمنسقين الأمنيين والإعلاميين والتي تقيمها الرابطة بالتعاون مع الاتحاد السعودي والاتحاد الآسيوي لكرة القدم",
            "thumbnails": {
                "default": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tnUz7fLwEBM/default.jpg",
                    "width": 120,
                    "height": 90
                },
                "medium": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tnUz7fLwEBM/mqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 320,
                    "height": 180
                },
                "high": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tnUz7fLwEBM/hqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 480,
                    "height": 360
                },
                "standard": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tnUz7fLwEBM/sddefault.jpg",
                    "width": 640,
                    "height": 480
                },
                "maxres": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tnUz7fLwEBM/maxresdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 1280,
                    "height": 720
                }
            },
            "channelTitle": "الدوري السعودي للمحترفين Saudi Pro League",
            "playlistId": "PLbJRbIvdAVXRdkBSpA25hugmJy_rOKOYu",
            "position": 2,
            "resourceId": {
                "kind": "youtube#video",
                "videoId": "tnUz7fLwEBM"
            }
        },
        "contentDetails": {
            "videoId": "tnUz7fLwEBM",
            "videoPublishedAt": "2018-07-27T17:34:19.000Z"
        }
    },
    {
        "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
        "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/AjA_MynNqIpjpuSN8kJmW7zgDlk\"",
        "id": "UExiSlJiSXZkQVZYUmRrQlNwQTI1aHVnbUp5X3JPS09ZdS41MjE1MkI0OTQ2QzJGNzNG",
        "snippet": {
            "publishedAt": "2018-08-17T02:59:33.000Z",
            "channelId": "UCqXAWrjSgLb0EPa_icPt-pw",
            "title": "حديث سلمان النمشان عن ورشة عمل مهام مراقبي ومنسقي المباريات والمنسقين الأمنيين والإعلاميين",
            "description": "سلمان بن نمشان رئيس لجنة مراقبي ومنسقي المباريات في رابطة الدوري السعودي للمحترفين يتحدث عن أهمية ورشة عمل مراقبي ومنسقي المباريات والمنسقين الأمنيين والإعلاميين والتي تقيمها الرابطة بالتعاون مع الاتحاد السعودي والاتحاد الآسيوي لكرة القدم",
            "thumbnails": {
                "default": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wIIGgdEa9DU/default.jpg",
                    "width": 120,
                    "height": 90
                },
                "medium": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wIIGgdEa9DU/mqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 320,
                    "height": 180
                },
                "high": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wIIGgdEa9DU/hqdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 480,
                    "height": 360
                },
                "standard": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wIIGgdEa9DU/sddefault.jpg",
                    "width": 640,
                    "height": 480
                },
                "maxres": {
                    "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wIIGgdEa9DU/maxresdefault.jpg",
                    "width": 1280,
                    "height": 720
                }
            },
            "channelTitle": "الدوري السعودي للمحترفين Saudi Pro League",
            "playlistId": "PLbJRbIvdAVXRdkBSpA25hugmJy_rOKOYu",
            "position": 3,
            "resourceId": {
                "kind": "youtube#video",
                "videoId": "wIIGgdEa9DU"
            }
        },
        "contentDetails": {
            "videoId": "wIIGgdEa9DU",
            "videoPublishedAt": "2018-07-27T17:24:59.000Z"
        }
    }
]
}
```

but am getting this error:

> Thread 2: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

in this line:

[image]

when the playlist id is this:

> PLSmSEc8Z6liq82OteppRm-koytegaPX2C

.. it's working just fine!

what is the problem? and how to solve this?

Comment: you force unwrap standard.url. Looks like it's nill.

Comment: @Taier but its not if you checked the response from postman

Comment: @Lama search your response with **XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/9bldgOrkQOmEy3P6x_T4pJiqAss** and you won't find standard path for this item

Answer (score 0):

In your response item id

```
"kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
"etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/9bldgOrkQOmEy3P6x_T4pJiqAss\""
```

hasn't thumbnails>standrad->url path value ( No **standrad** key )